# ¿Existe una función en PHP que me permita calcular en que fecha cae a partir de otra una cantidad de días sin contar los sábados y domingos?

Tags: php, date, calculo

¿Existe una función en PHP que me permita calcular que fecha cae a partir de otra fecha una cantidad de días sin contar los sábados y domingos?

Por ejemplo, ¿Qué fecha cae a partir del 11 de Mayo  si sumo 60 días laborales (osea sin contar Sábado y Domingo) ?

Gracias

Comment: Este es tu exacto problema ?? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days

Comment: NO, No requiero saber cuantos días laborales hay entre DOS fechas, lo que necesito es que A PARTIR de una fecha sume N cantidad de días laborables (no sábados y no domingos) y me arroje en que fecha cayó.

Comment: Entiendo... deja ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré esta solución en internet... podrías testearla.
-> https://gist.github.com/finbar-crago/2553430

```
<?PHP
function addBizDays($start, $add){
  $start = strtotime($start);
  $d = min(date('N',$start),5);
  $start -= date('N',$start) * 24 * 60 * 60;
  $w = (floor( $add / 5 ) * 2);
  $r = $add + $w + $d;
  return date('Y-m-d', strtotime( date("Y-m-d", $start) . " +$r day") );
}

echo addBizDays('2021-05-11',10),'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Por que dan dislike sin comentar ?? no entiendo...

Comment: parece que si funciona!! Gracias

Comment: @IvanCaballeroCano, si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que esta puede ser la solución.